# how to get over the fear of doing a backhandspring

Tags: gymnastics

I'm 11 yrs old, and have been doing gymnastics for about 2 1/2 years. I'm a level 4 gymnast, but I can't get over the fear of jumping into my back handspring. Since I only go to the gym one time a week, and only have a beam and a mat at home, does anyone know a way to help me get over the fear of jumping into my back handspring?

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally speaking, the technique generally used for training a person for a back handspring involves either a spotter with their hand lightly on your back, ready to push up if you need it, or a giant foam roller so that you can literally roll through the movement at first. Other than that, the other bit of advice I seen is doing the back handspring a little bit sideways, what Capoeira generally calls a *[macaco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwWKvLzSU9c)*. Because you're not going straight back, it's a lot less scary. Once you feel comfortable doing one from a standing position, you start trying to do it more and more straight over your head until you're able to plant that other hand, at which point you are doing a back handspring.